# The pads for a switch on my ODROID-XU4 are destroyed. Can it be saved?

Tags: pcb-layers

I have an issue with a switch which selects if the ODROID-XU4 shall use the eMMC or the SD card. As you can see, as I tried to fix it, I destroyed the pads. Only one pad is still intact (eMMC.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get a schematic of the [ODROID-XU4 here.](https://dn.odroid.com/5422/ODROID-XU4/Schematics/)

That shows how the switch is connected:

[image]

One side of the slide switch connects to ground while the other side connects to VDD_IO (1.8V) through a resistor.  The center connection is the signal.  It goes to Q4 (a [2N7002W N-channel MOSFET](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11303.pdf)) and to the microprocessor somewhere (XOM_2, B20.)

The easiest thing to do would be to connect a single pole double throw switch in place of the original.  I'd just wire it "flying" to the ground and VDD_IO through a resistor with a third wire going to the gate of Q4.  I'd probably hot glue the wires to the board or use a zip-tie to hold the wires in place on one of the screw holes on the board.

The only real difficulty is that as far as I can tell, Q4 is under the heat sink of the processor.

[image]

<sub>[Image source](https://media.mickmake.com//post/odroid-xu4-an-sbc-on-roids-review//images/ODROID-XU4p02.jpg)</sub>

The original switch is marked as well as what I think is the gate of Q4.  If it is Q4 then the gate is marked correctly according to the 2N7002 datasheet. The picture is somewhat blurry - I don't own an ODROID-XU4 so I had to borrow the best picture I could find.

VDD_IO and ground are available on the [CON10 header on the XU4:](https://pi4j.com/1.2/pins/odroid-xu4.html#CON10_Pinout_30-pin_Header)

[image]

Pin 29 is VDD_IO (1.8V.) Pin 30 is ground.

A new switch, a few pieces of wire, a resistor, and some careful soldering should get it back to work.

---

Instead of connecting a switch, you might find it easier to just wire the gate of Q4 to VDD_IO or ground to "fix" the external memory setting.  It would be neater than the switch, but you'd lose the ability to change the setup.  If you only use one setting most of the time then that may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a hard repair without knowing what the pads connected to. The traces could be 5-10 thousands of an inch wide that connect to the pads and they could be buried on an inner layer.

The main problem is I can't even see where copper extended to the outside of the pad broken off. If you find that you might be able to get an exacto knife and carefully pull back the top layer, however this is a multi-layer board it could be more than four layers so you might do more damage than good if other traces are in the way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what is left to connect to, but if you go to YouTube and search for "pcb pad repair" there are dozens of videos showing you how to do it for various scenarios. It looks as if you might be able to epoxy a small piece of thin copper foil to the board and bridge it to the correct track - there are videos showing you how to do this.